# Joomla Login Username & Password Getting Filled In Automatically

Tags: caching, joomla, joomla2.5, cache-control

I had turned on Joomla cache for a while I came across that Joomla login username & password getting filled in automatically. So I turned of cache and happened to be working for the small period of time. Now I experience the same issue even when Joomla cache is turned off.

Given that Joomla automatically cache in the root folder. In the root, There is a folder called `cache` and inside there is a folder called `pages`. When it delete the `pages` folder it happens to be working fine.

How can I fix this? What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you have enabled auto fill options on your browser and your browser is filling them automatically when same page loads.

If you want to disable page cache, go to Plugin Manager and disable System - Cache plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The website cache has nothing to do with forms being autofilled. That is a browser function.

Comment: Actually it has because when I disable jommla cache site happens to work fine. For me and all the other users too. Site has more than 1000 users.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then because Joomla does not cache usernames and passwords. That is a browser function.